# Using trap to terminate a function in bash

Tags: bash, process, ipc

I have a function in bash, call it "timer", that simply displays number of seconds elapsed. Presently, it runs in a separate process, and the parent process kills it when it is done.

I wish the function to to trap a signal somehow and exit gracefully, but I have no idea how. Here is an example script as it is now:

```
#!/bin/bash

function timer () {

  t0=$(date +%s)

  while true ; do
    t=$(date +%s)
    echo -en "\r$(($t - $t0))"
  done
}

timer &
pid=$!
echo $pid

sleep 5 # do something while timer runs
echo "done"
kill -9 $pid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. Don't use `kill -9` to kill it. `SIGKILL` is uncatchable. It doesn't let the target process do any cleanup. Just do a plain `kill` to send a `SIGTERM` signal.
2. You can trap on `SIGTERM`. You could also trap on `SIGINT` to catch Ctrl-C. Or best, trap on `EXIT` to do cleanup no matter how the script is killed.

```
function timer () {
  trap 'echo -e "\ntimer stopped"' EXIT

  t0=$(date +%s)

  while true ; do
    t=$(date +%s)
    echo -en "\r$(($t - $t0))"
  done
}

timer &
pid=$!
echo "$pid"

sleep 5 # do something while timer runs
echo "done"
kill "$pid"
```